# Removing an impaled object without a doctor

Tags: first-aid, emergency

We all know (or at least, we should) that you should never remove an impaling object. Keep the object as still and stable as possible, and wait for the EMT/doctor/surgeon/whatever to do it.

But what if that's not an option? Say, two people are castaways on a remote island, with no communication with the outside world. They're making primitive bows to hunt with, there's an accident, and one person now has an arrow stuck through them. What should they do?

Comment: @JiminyCricket. No, this isn't for fiction, just for my own curiosity. Every resource I could find on how to treat impalement says "keep it still and wait for the professionals"; I couldn't find even one source on what to do if there are no professionals available.

Comment: Pretty much all impaled objects have to be removed at some point, otherwise the risk of infection is too high. However, removing an impaled object carries two immediate risks: worsening the bleeding (like removing the cork of a bottle), and worsening the injury (further tearing the flesh, organs, or whatever else is close to the impaled object.) Since these two risks are extremely high, and have much more urgent consequences than the risk of infection, it is very strongly advised to always leave the object in, and wait for a professional to remove it.

Comment: In fact, even EMT would typically not remove the object, and wait for a surgeon.

Comment: But if there is no professional because you're Robinson Crusoe, then you'll have to remove the object yourself.

Answer (score 4):

According to a [reputable wilderness rescue training organization](https://sierrarescue.com/tag/wilderness-first-aid/#:%7E:text=Wilderness%20medicine%20guidelines%20suggest%20that,minimize%20the%20risk%20of%20infection.), these are the guidelines taught in wilderness medicine that you should follow for impalements:

> **Core  impalement.** Impalements to the head, face, trunk and other core
> parts of the body are usually left in place. Primary focus should be
> on bleeding control and secondary efforts to stabilize the object in
> place with sterile bulky dressing. Minimizing movement of the
> impalement will help to reduce subsequent damage. In some cases when
> the impalement is from a larger object, consider reducing the size of
> the object to facilitate evacuation.  Impalements to the eyes get
> special attention. Not only does the object require stabilization in
> place over the affected eye, but the unaffected eye needs to be
> covered since movement of one eye is linked to the other.
>
> **Extremity Impalement.**  Wilderness medicine guidelines suggest that
> impalements to the extremities can be removed to facilitate
> evacuation. If your patient can or needs to self evacuate, prior
> removal of the impaled object can help. Proper wound management will
> help minimize the risk of infection. In some cases extremity
> impalements remain stabilized in place.
>
> **Basic Life Support.**   Any impalement that interferes with a basic life
> support intervention can be removed. For example, if CPR is indicated
> based on patient assessment, and an impalement would impede proper
> CPR, the removal of the impalement is acceptable

If you do remove the object, there will be external bleeding, and at least some degree of internal bleeding you can't see. There's nothing you can do about internal bleeding, so focus on external bleeding. The first step should always be direct pressure. Use whatever absorbent cloth you can get your hands on (a t-shirt will work well). Elevate the body part above the level of the heart if possible and apply forceful, continuous pressure on the wound for at least 15 minutes.  If that doesn't stop the bleeding or at least slow it significantly and the wound is in an extremity, consider a tourniquet. But make this choice as a last resort because you are very likely sacrificing the limb. You cannot remove the tourniquet after about 2 hours even if you think the bleeding has stopped permanently because the limb will be full of toxic waste products and flushing that blood back into the systemic circulation could kill the patient. You can, however, slowly begin to loosen the tourniquet after about an hour to see if the bleeding has stopped. If it has, go ahead and release it but otherwise it probably needs to remain on until medical help can be reached.